# Look for duplicates in two columns

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

The below code looks for duplicates in Column A, and if a duplicate exists,  sets the adjacent cell in column H to 0.

I want to amend it to look for duplicates in column A as well as E, and if both are duplicates to set the adjacent cell in column H to 0.

```vb
Dim Cell As Range
    Dim DSO As Object
    Dim Rng As Range
       
    Set Rng = Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    
    Set DSO = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    DSO.CompareMode = 1
     
    For Each Cell In Rng
        If DSO.Exists(Cell.Text) Then
            Cell.Offset(0, 7) = 0
        Else
            DSO.Add Cell.Text, Cell
        End If
    Next Cell
    
    Set DSO = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want to check if A# is dupe AND if E# is dupe, or if A#+E# is a dupe

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```vb
Sub Dups()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, DSO As Object, Cell As Range, k

    Set DSO = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    DSO.CompareMode = 1 'case-insensitive
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'or some other sheet...
    For Each Cell In ws.Range("A1", ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Cells
        k = Cell.Value & Chr(0) & Cell.EntireRow.Columns("E").Value 'create the key value
        If DSO.exists(k) Then
            Cell.EntireRow.Columns("H").Value = 0
        Else
            DSO.Add k, Cell '.Value ?
        End If
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

Comment: I like your `Cell.EntireRow.Columns("E").Value = 0` better than my `Cell.Offset(0, 4)` as it is likely easier for an average user to change.

Comment: Mine's a bit more "bulky" though - maybe better inside a `With Cell.EntireRow` block...

Comment: I'm not sure how much more clarity/legibility it would offer. I'm a sucker for a good `With` statement though.  - - - Why did you chose a null character for your delimiter?

Comment: Wait, I just though about it.... It's highly unlikely you'll find a null char "in the wild". It's the best choice

Comment: Yep I used to use something like "~~~" as a joiner, but you never know...

Answer (score 0):

I just added a second dictionary and checked both:

```
Sub CheckDupes()

    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim DSO1 As Object
    Dim DSO2 As Object
    Dim Rng As Range
    
    Set Rng = Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
     
    Set DSO1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    DSO1.CompareMode = 1
    Set DSO2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    DSO1.CompareMode = 1
     
        For Each Cell In Rng
            If DSO1.Exists(Cell.Text) And DSO2.Exists(Cell.Offset(0, 4).Text) Then
                Cell.Offset(0, 7) = 0
            Else
                If Not DSO1.Exists(Cell.Text) Then _
                    DSO1.Add Cell.Text, Cell
                If Not DSO2.Exists(Cell.Offset(0, 4).Text) Then _
                    DSO2.Add Cell.Offset(0, 4).Text, Cell.Offset(0, 4)
            End If
        Next Cell
    
    Set DSO1 = Nothing
    Set DSO2 = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Example:

[image]

Comment: To note, this solution will check if both items are duplicates with respect to their column only. Not if the concatenation of A#+E# is a dupe.